# boost::asio::io_service in thread, does not exit on application exit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have an application that uses `boost::asio::io_service` to listen for client connections. I am running this in a thread, with the loop below:

```
static auto const flags = boost::archive::no_header | boost::archive::no_tracking;
      while (!_exit)
            {
                boost::asio::io_service ios;
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint
                    = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);
                acceptor = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(ios, endpoint);
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;

                // program stops here until client connects.
                acceptor->accept(*stream->rdbuf());


                //grab the incoming data using 
                 boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(*stream);
                 archive << data;

        }
```

If a client connects, the data comes in and all is well. If I try to close the application before the client connects, the thread does not die.  I cannot use `_exit = true` to break out of the loop, I assume this is because it is stuck waiting for a client that never connects.

How can i kill this thread properly, while the acceptor is waiting?

Comment: one way is to use asynchronous API and use cancel on acceptor. When synchronous API is used I have no idea.

Comment: would that be with `acceptor.async_accept`?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp

Answer (score 1):

How do you "try to close the application before the client connects"?

If you're using regular methods, you could likely handle the signal:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html

Other than that, there is in principle no way to cancel an synchronous accept, but you can fake it by connecting to your own listening end, thus making `accept` return.

Comment: I am inside Unreal Engine, and i simply close the Editor. The process does not die, even though the editor is closed. I will try to fake it. thanks!